# eclipse can't import pyqtgraph

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqtgraph

I've recently downloaded and installed pyqtgraph, but I can't make it work with eclipse. I tried running this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph 
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

#QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
#mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
#mw.resize(800,800)


win = pyqtgraph.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")

win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pyqtgraph.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p1 = win.addPlot(title="Basic array plotting", y=np.random.normal(size=100))

p1.setLabel('left', "Y Axis", units='A')
p1.setLabel('bottom', "Y Axis", units='s')
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "L:\workspace\FDM\pyqtgraph.py", line 4, in  import pyqtgraph
>
> File "L:\workspace\FDM\pyqtgraph.py", line 13, in  win =
>   pyqtgraph.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphicsWindow'

I tried listing pyqtgraph under the forced builtins list, but i still gives me the same error. I also checked the pyqtgraph folder and it does have the fole for GraphicsWindow.

The import does work when I use iPython.....

Comment: Are you sure the name "pyqtgraph" actually refers to the pyqtgraph library? Try adding `print pyqtgraph.__file__` after the import statement.

Comment: ok I feel bad now, I just notice that I names my example pyqtgraph... Thanks man!